# Getting native Oracle column type in schema from MS OracleClient

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, system.data.oracleclient

I am using the deprecated System.Data.OracleClient from Microsoft to perform some remote querying of Oracle tables. I am technically unable to use the Oracle-provided ODP providers, regrettably, for reasons that aren't relevant here.

In performing a query, I would like to get the string representation of the Oracle type for a given column, and am relying on the GetSchemaTable() method of the OraceDataReader to have this information. I'm finding several things that are *close*, but not what I'm really looking for. This seems almost a ridiculously simple request.

I've tried several things that seemed hopeful, but were red herrings: I found the `SchemaTableOptionalColumn.ProviderSpecificDataType` column to return the *Microsoft provider* type name (eg. `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleNumber`), but all I want is the literal column type as defined in Oracle, eg `NVARCHAR` or `NUMBER`. I thought perhaps the `ProviderType` property, which returns a number, would map to the `OracleType` enumeration in the provider, but it doesn't. The other hope, `DataType` really maps more to the corresponding managed type of the column, which isn't what I'm looking for, either.

I thought surely someone has solved this before, but if they have, I've not yet found the right rock under which to look for it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot test it, but it sounds like just want this method: [OracleDataReader.GetDataTypeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.getdatatypename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which gives you the dataType of a specific column of your query result.

Comment: Absolutely perfect!!! I cannot BELIEVE I never saw that. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!!